# How can I apply changes made to a jsf component from javascript?

Tags: javascript, jsf

I have two jsf inputText whose class I change dynamically from javascript. These inputText's class starts being numeric and after some conditions they change to alphanumeric.

```
<h:form id="mainForm">
<h:inputText id="otraIdUno"
   ...
   class="form-control soloNumeros" maxlength="15"
   ...>
</h:inputText>
```

From chrome, if I inspect the element, I can see the changes on the class but nothing is happening on the inputText itself, I mean I just can type numbers and not letters.

```
<h:inputText id="otraIdUno"
   ...
   class="form-control alfanumerico" maxlength="15"
   ...>
</h:inputText>
```

From javascript I'm setting the inputText's class this way:

```
$("#mainForm\\:otraIdUno").addClass("alfanumerico");
```

A friend told me to try to update the element with this instruction but it didn't work.

```
$("#mainForm\\:otraIdUno").load(location.href + " #mainForm\\:otraIdUno");
```

I also tried setting the event again after adding the class:

```
$(".soloNumeros").keypress(onlyNumbers);
$(".alfanumerico").keypress(alphaNumeric);
```

I wont put here *onlyNumbers* and *alphaNumeric* code as they are just regular functions and they are already working with other elements.

**By the way, if I set the class before running the code in any of these inputText it works perfectly. It isn't working only when I set it dynamically.**

What I want is these inputText to be numeric in some cases and alphanumeric in other cases but they are always numeric.

Comment: Does this work using plain html? I don't see anything realy related to jsf in this problem. You try to make client-side  changes to the html that was rendered by jsf, not to the server side jsf components

Comment: You mean that I'm just using class attribute and javascript, right? I mentioned jsf because this is a jsf form and jsf inputText and that has caused me issues with other code before.

Comment: Yes.. But instead of JSF itself, most likely the way you (try to) (ab)use it is what is causing problems. And the suggestion by a friend is weird too. And keep in mind that yiu now circumvent all great features of jsf like owasp, client-side manipulation, etc...

Comment: Oh, I see. In that case, how can I apply these changes to the html components? By the way, I'm doing some tests and I'm seeing that the inputText is being duplicated. One input has the class "alfanumerico" and the other one has the class "soloNumeros". I guess this is causing the problem, but I don't see why this duplication is happening.

Comment: Then read about [mcve].

Comment: Great, thanks for the info.